# php artisan command does not work anymore

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project based on version **5.4**.

today I found that `php artisan` does not work any more and for all commands return this error :

```
Could not open input file: artisan
```

This is while working well before and have not any problem.

Of course in other laravel project all things worked find and There is no problem.

I have searched in google and I have reviewed a lot of topics But none of their solutions resolved the problem.

**Update:**

I found that there is not any artisan file in root directory. I do not know what happened.

Also I downloaded `artisan` file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/master/artisan and add to my project but problem not solved.

Comment: are you sure you are in the directory in which laravel is installed?

Comment: Check your file permissions. If you are able to access the file with `sudo`, you most likely have wrong permissions.

Comment: Is the file 'artisan' found in the directory you're in?

Comment: What have you change after when it was working last time ?

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz, Yes I sure and check many times

Comment: @Namoshek, I'm using wamp and I think that `sudo` does not work on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue a few times here are the steps I'd take to triage the cause you can run artisan in order:

1. Ensure you are in the root path of the laravel project and that the artisan file exists in that path. If you aren't in the path that contains the artisan executable (the root of your laravel project) you will get this error. If you aren't in the root path of your laravel project you'll see this

   `┌─[admin@nfml-5YF]─(~)
   └─[18:24]$ php artisan
   Could not open input file: artisan`
2. Ensure your artisan file has the right file permissions (should be 644 on linux). (I changed it to 222 just to show reproduce an issue).

   1. Check the file's current permissions.

   `┌─[admin@nfml-5YF]─(/reviewrail)
    └─[16:49]$ stat -f '%A %a %N' artisan
    222 1527108561 artisan`

   If you run artisan without execute permissions, you will get the error you reference.
    `┌─[admin@nfml-5YF]─(/reviewrail)
    └─[16:49]$ php artisan inspire
    Could not open input file: artisan`

   2. If change file permissions to 644.   Give it another shot and it should work.

   `┌─[admin@nfml-5YF]─(/reviewrail)
    └─[16:50]$ chmod 644 artisan
    ┌─[admin@nfml-5YF]─(/reviewrail)
    └─[16:50]$ php artisan inspire
    Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration. - Thomas Edison`